# Subscribe to Redis Instance in Azure using redis-cli in Docker

Tags: docker, redis, publish-subscribe

I have a Redis instance running in Azure, and I have the connection string. I want to subscribe to it from the command line using redis-cli running in a Docker container. I can do this when I run redis locally, using the command

```
docker run -it --link redisDev:redis --rm redis redis-cli -h redis -p 6379:6739
```

However I can't figure out how to use the connection string for a remote instance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you telnet that remote redis instance? is it exposed on the web? is the `connection string` an URI?

It should be as easy as providing the right host to the `-h` param.